# STL iterator with custom template

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, stl

i have the following template method,

```
template <class T>
void Class::setData( vector<T> data )
{    
    vector<T>::iterator it;
}
```

and i'm getting the following compilation error ( XCode/gcc )

> error: expected `;' before 'it'

i found someone else with a similar problem [here (read down to see it's the same even though it starts out with a different issue)](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-221670.html) but they seem to have resolved by updating Visual Studio. This makes me guess that it is a compiler issue and that it should compile, is that correct? Iteration via indexing from 0 to size works, however it is not the way i would prefer to implement this function. Is there another way around this?
Thanks

Comment: Note: consider passing in "vector<T> &data", or maybe  "vector<T> const &data" not "vector<T> data".  The former two will pass in a reference to the vector, the latter will make a full copy of the vector.

Comment: Of course, it was just an example :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Classic case of when to use the `typename` keyword. Hoping that you have `#include`-ed `vector` and `iterator` and have a `using namespace std;` somewhere in scope. Use:

```
typename vector<T>::iterator it;
```

Look up dependent names. Start [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a `typename`:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Class{
public:
    template <class T>
    void setData( vector<T> data ) {
        typename vector<T>::iterator it;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
template <class T>
void Class::setData( std::vector<T> data )
{    
    std::vector<T>::iterator it;
}
```

Just is case it's a missing `using` statement?

Comment: If he had missed the using statement he would also get an error on the function signature.