# Template Function under GCC

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

**Duplicate. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594521/stl-iterator-with-custom-template/594630#594630).**

Can someone tell me why this does not compile under GCC?  Both MSVC6, and VS2008 will compile it, with no warnings, even.

The code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
T range(vector<T> &v)
{
   vector<T>::iterator i = v.begin();
```

Throws an error on the last line, expected ; before i.

Do I need to typedef?

Most of the compiling I do is with MSVC6, or VS2008.  I don't do a whole lot with GCC, so I'm a little in the dark.

Comment: I really do not want this question closed.  Yes, there is a duplicate question and answer posted, but mine has references to gcc in the body, where the other question does not.  This is an important factor, until SO can link dupe questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler does not know enough to parse vector::iterator as a type at that point. Use the typename keyword to give it a hint:

```
typename vector<T>::iterator i = v.begin();
```